# PHP: How to combine array when parameter are not equal

Tags: php, arrays

I Combine Two Array As follow.

```
<?php
    $array1 = array(1,3,5,7,8,9,10);
    $array2 = array(2,6,10,14,16);

    $array4 = array_combine($array1, $array2);
?>
```

But What if I don't have same array Element?

I try that it will return this error

> array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

As example if I have `$array1` count is 5 and `$array2` count is 6.
So how can I combine this two array.

Comment: I think you want http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php It says array_combine — Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values so pretty sure you don't want to do that.

Comment: What you are asking does not make sense with the term "combine". Maybe you want to saw us an output of what you are expecting or try describe better what you want to do.

Comment: i need combination in Associative Arrays.

Comment: What you might need is array_merge_recursive(...) when dealing with associative arrays... http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_combine` will use the keys of the first array and the values of the second. Therefore both arrays will need the same number of items for this to work.

To combine all values of two arrays into a single array you'll need to use `array_merge`.

`array_merge($array1, $array2);`

Comment: Array_merge will merge the two 10 keys under the same one so will lose one element